# Displaying Text in ASP Content from C# Code

Tags: c#, asp.net

This question most likely has an easy solution, but I cannot figure it out. I have a .aspx page with the following code:

```
<%@ Page Title="Update ASV Information" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="UpdateASV.aspx.cs" Inherits="COAF_Process_to_ASV_Relation_Tool.UpdateASV" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server" >
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server">
</asp:PlaceHolder>
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="asv_update" OnClick="asvUpdate_Click" Text="Update    ASV" />
</asp:Content>
```

I want to be able to write text from the C# code behind this page (UpdateASV.aspx.cs). Whenever I try:

```
Response.Write("some text");
```

It puts the code behind the content2 placeholder. I want it inside. Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Is there a reason not to use **Label** or **Literal** control? Are you trying to add text to Master page from ASPX page?

Comment: I basically have that placeholder producing a bunch of textboxes dynamically in the code behind, but I want to have breaks in between them, so I thought I would have to have those in the actual C# code.

Comment: Omg I got it, I was putting my label in the wrong method!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Response.Write directly modifies the response.  You don't want to do that in your web forms application.  You should be modifying the contents of a Label, Literal, or PlaceHolder control from the code-behind.

Use Label to put text into the page

Use Literal to put raw html into the page

Use PlaceHolder to add new controls to the page dynamically.

Either way, the placement of the control(Label, Literal, or PlaceHolder) on your page determines where on the page your output will be rendered.

Comment: And don't tell anyone I know about web forms stuff.  They might make me work on a web forms app.

Answer (score 0):

If you are determined to stick to server side controls:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostback)
    {
        Literal myText = new Literal() 
        { 
            Text = "some text" 
        };
        Content2.Controls.Add(myText);
    }
}
```

Otherwise, just put the code inline

```
<%=Response.Write("some text") %>
```